# How to style vaadin-upload-file component inside Vaadin Upload

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14, vaadin-upload

I would like to style Vaadin Upload component (`vaadin-upload`) by changing appearance of the elements in file list, e.g. hide commands buttons (start, remove, retry). The file list contains `vaadin-upload-file` elements.

For now I'm only able to customize vaadin-upload itself by adding custom theme to it and importing proper css - just like in this example: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/large-upload-area.

```java
@CssImport(value = "./styles/custom-upload.css", themeFor = "vaadin-upload")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements HasUrlParameter<String> {

    public MainView() {
        Upload upload = new Upload();
        upload.getElement().getThemeList().add("custom-upload");
        add(upload);
    }
}
```

custom-upload.css:

```js
:host([theme~="custom-upload"]) {
  border: 0;
}

:host([theme~="custom-upload"]) [part="commands"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Simplified DOM:

```html
<vaadin-upload theme="custom-upload" target="VAADIN/dynamic/resource/1/70860bf9-21c4-474e-9418-fd5516c28736/upload">
    #shadow-root
        <div part="primary-buttons">...</div>
        <slot name="file-list">
            <div id="fileList" part="file-list">
                <vaadin-upload-file>...</vaadin-upload-file>
            </div>
        </slot>
        ...
</vaadin-upload>
```

Documentation states that:

- vaadin-upload-file has customizable parts (e.g. `commands`) https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-upload/html-api/elements/Vaadin.UploadFileElement.
- moreover, `theme` value should be propagated to all sub-components according to https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/styling-components/#sub-components - which seems to be not the case.

Is there a way to attach custom `theme` to vaadin-upload-file component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you just need a separate style module targeting the `vaadin-upload-file` component, which is doable using the `@CssImport` annotation. For example,

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/custom-upload-file.css", themeFor = "vaadin-upload-file")
```

Then the custom CSS can be added to `{project_root}/frontend/styles/custom-upload-file.css`.

**EDIT:** unlike other Vaadin components, a theme name that is assigned to `vaadin-upload` doesn't (unfortunately) get propagated down to `vaadin-upload-file`. Thus, one cannot rely on the theme attribute in order to selectively style some `vaadin-upload-file` components within the same application.

If selective styling is necessary, a hacky workaround is possible by making a JavaScript call that adds a classname to the `vaadin-upload-file` component. Such call would, however, only work after the `vaadin-upload-file` is rendered in the DOM (which typically occurs upon the success of a file upload). Hence, the JS call should be made from within an upload-success listener.

Here's this workaround in action used to selectively hide the clear button of the `vaadin-upload-file`:

```
@Route
@CssImport(value = "./styles/vaadin-upload-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-upload-file")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {

        MemoryBuffer buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
        Upload upload = new Upload(buffer);
        upload.addSucceededListener(e -> {
            upload.getElement()
                    .executeJs("this.shadowRoot.querySelector('vaadin-upload-file').className = 'hidden-clear'");
        });

        Button showClear = new Button("Show clear button", e -> upload.getElement()
                .executeJs("this.shadowRoot.querySelector('vaadin-upload-file').className = ''"));

        add(upload, showClear);
    }

}
```

Then in `vaadin-upload-styles.css`, one can do something like:

```
:host(.hidden-clear) [part~=clear-button] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to add this theme to `vaadin-upload-file`, i.e. how can I get this object to call `getThemeList().add("custom-upload-file")` on it?

Comment: @kamillo Unfortunately theme propagation is not consistently implemented in all components, and vaadin-upload is one component where theme propagation does not work. Furthermore, there is no API to access the file upload element directly. I'm afraid currently you can only theme upload files for all uploads. You might want to raise an issue here: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components.

Comment: Thank for explanation @SaschaIßbrücker. After all I think I'm ok with styling all upload files components the same way.

Comment: @kamillo FYI, a hacky workaround is possible via making a JS call that adds a classname to the `vaadin-upload-file` component. This workaround is demoed here: https://github.com/tarekoraby/upload-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/org/vaadin/example/MainView.java

Comment: I edited the answer to mention this workaround.

Comment: @TarekOraby hi, how to do with Vaadin 23 ? i am try but nothing, vaadin can`t read  @CssImport.

Comment: @TarekOraby I resolved it, create a components dir inside my themes dir, but i am not using the @CssImport, and use ```@import url('components/vaadin-upload-file.css');``` in main styles.css

Answer (score 2):

To modify the style in a Vaadin Web Component extending `ThemableMixin`, you can

- do what Tarek said, or
- create a custom theme with a file named `vaadin-upload-file.css` in the `components` folder. Read more [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/custom-theme/#theme-folder-structure).

Either way, you need to understand that `ThemeList#add(String)` is just appending the argument to the `theme` attribute on the client side. So, you just need to handle the new theme in CSS, for example:

```css
:host([theme~="prettypink"]) [part="done-icon"]::before {
    color: #ff31f1;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-upload/blob/master/theme/lumo/vaadin-upload-styles.html) are the default Lumo styles for `vaadin-upload` and `vaadin-upload-file`.